# How to stop execution of a Request in Kohana?

Tags: php, exception, request, kohana-3

Let's say I have a controller template with a before function like so...

```
public function before()
  {
     parent::before();
     if ($this->request === Request::instance()) 
     {
         // its a main request, throw an exception or redirect
         Request::instance()->redirect('/');
     }
     else
     {
        // ok
     }
  }
```

But let's say I don't want to redirect, I want to stop the Request flow, and do nothing.

Does an exception do this? Is there a simple way, like `Request::die();`?

EDIT:: I actually don't want to halt the Request flow, just prevent this controller from doing anything.  It's likely that this controller was called from another controller, and I want to pass the control back to the calling controller.'

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with regular `die()`?

Comment: "Do nothing" as in completely stop and not display anything? Like Tesserex said, `die`

Comment: Nothing wrong at all. So inside the if statement, you just put die(); ? What if there are other sub-controller calls after this sub-controller is called? Will it only stop this controller's action, or the whole script?  I want to only stop this controller, but pass control back to the calling controller if there is one.

Comment: die will stop execution entirely for everything except other threads. I don't know if Kohana is multi-threaded but I sorta doubt it. So it's roughly equivalent to throwing a fatal error; everything comes to a screeching halt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use exceptions (not tested yet):

```
try
(
   Request->instance()->execute();
}
catch (MyRequest_Exception $e)
{
   // do what you want
}

echo Request->instance()->send_headers->response();

// somewhere in before()
if ($error)
{
   throw new MyRequest_Exception($errortext);
}
```

1. Change action name:

   $this->request->action('oblivion'); // redirects to an "oblivion" action that does nothing

Comment: Right now, I'm just calling a fake action, but I want to use exceptions, so I'm picking this. If I find it doesn't work, I'll come back and update this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class variable in `before()` say:

```
$this->execute = false;
```

Then in your action:

```
public function action_example()
{
    if (!$this->execute) return;
    // etc
}
```